How to prevent specific static files (e.g., hashed JS files) from being exposed in HTTP requests using Wget with ASP.NET Core?
i'm using ASP.NET Core as the backend for my Angular application. When I make requests to the server (e.g., using Wget), I notice that hashed JavaScript files like external-module.d1aa0dsdp55.js are being listed and exposed in the request details (in the raw section). These files are automatically generated by Angular, and I want to prevent them from being visible to the client or exposed through HTTP requests.
I have tried to configure the static file settings in ASP.NET Core, but I haven't been able to hide these files from the request logs.
Any suggestions or examples on how to achieve this would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.
As you can see in the attached screenshot, the JS file appears in the request, but I don't want it to be present there.
enter image description here

Please post the error as text, not screenshot.

The HTML that is returned with your initial request sources that file. That usually means it's required for execution, if that's true then blocking access means breaking the page?

My problem is that when the request is sent, I don't want it to return the desired file

@NickSlash It shouldn't be a problem to load the page, but when I hit www.test.com/external-module.js, for example, no information should be returned.

It will be a problem if that code is needed by the client. If your trying to protect or keep your code secret, you can't.

@NickSlash Running http://localhost:4200/external-module2.js is required to start the project, but I want no information to be given if this address is run in the browser.

Is it to secure your code? If it is then you might be able to block certain methods but you will not stop people from getting the code.

I think you'd better to change your point of view. let's look to the project as MVC.
Users absolutely know nothing about your model & controller layer, but the view layer is the place where they rule.
So if you have something in view layer like static files (such as wwwroot folder) as an example, it seems not logical to completely hide it from them.
you don't want them to see your logic? Ok, put it in controller layer, otherwise configure ASP.NET Core to limit their crawling on your public folders.
Remember , Any thing you transfer to client system via HTTP or any other transfer protocol are owned by client's and they can see it.
You can make it hard for them to understand to what they deal with by encrypting or ... , but not impossible.
